# MariaDB Describe command error

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb, mariadb-connect-engine

using MariaDB for a Database Systems module in college. When I enter the database and use a certain table, I want to run the 'DESCRIBE' command. However when I do so 'DESCRIBE example_table', I am presented by a huge string of random characters like this

> ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,'

I was wondering if anyone had encountered this error before and if so, how did you fix it?

Comment: Does it happen with every table? Do you create the table yourself? Which client do you use? Can you paste the whole unabridged output from your client -- `CREATE TABLE` followed by `DESCRIBE`, with all output that each of them gives? If you are not creating the table yourself, are you able to run `SHOW CREATE TABLE ..` normally, and if so, can you paste its output? Finally, which exact MariaDB version is it?

Comment: Also, why is it tagged "mariadb-connect-engine"? Is it a CONNECT table?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually asking for my sister who is using MariaDB for her course. I'll get the full output later on when I see her. She definitely didn't create the table herself, so I'll try that command and send on the output later on today. Didn't mean the mariadb-connect-engine tag!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved incase it happens to anyone else. All that was wrong is that she was using the incorrect command line parameters to kick off to SQL session (I think she was using a -p instead of a -r or something like that)